# How to plot coordinates from single pandas series

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas series called `df1['geometry.coordinates']` of coordinate values in the following format:

```
geometry.coordinates
0   [150.792711, -34.210868]
1   [151.551228, -33.023339]
2   [148.92149870748742, -34.767207772932835]
3   [151.033742, -33.919998]
4   [150.953963043732, -32.3935017885229]
...     ...
432     [114.8927165, -28.902492300000002]
433     [115.34601918477634, -30.041742290803096]
434     [115.4632611, -30.8581035]
435     [121.42151909999998, -30.7804027]
436     [115.69424934340425, -30.680970908597665]
```

I want to plot each point on a graph, probably through using a scatter plot.

I tried: `df1['geometry.coordinates'].plot.scatter()` but it gets confused because it only reads it as one list value rather than two and therefore I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: scatter() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: Split array into multiple columns**

```
df1[['x','y']] = pd.DataFrame(df1['geometry.coordinates'].tolist(), index= df1.index)
```

**Step 2: Plot**

```
df1.plot.scatter(x = 'x', y = 'y', s = 30) #s is size of dots
```

[image: Tried at my end]
[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought this might work but I get the following error now:
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: getting this error at the step 1?

Comment: Yes at step 1, converting to a list works fine, but the error happens when the list is in the dataframe

Comment: I just tried it at my end using the values you posted. Works perfectly fine here. Can you post a snippet of the code you are using?

Comment: I did it exactly as you wrote, I just tried it using just the two values you did and that worked. I think it might be because I have NaN values in the series, I'll try get rid of them and give it another go.

Comment: Ok dropping the NaNs worked, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the column containing the list so that you can specify x and y in the plot call.

You can split a column containing a list by constructing a data frame from a list.

```
pd.DataFrame(df2["geometry.coordinates"].to_list(), columns=['x', 'y']).plot.scatter(x=“x”, y=“y”)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the parameters to `scatter()`, so the error is quite logical. Something among the lines of `df.scatter.plot(df[0],df[1])` should work.

Also, as you are working working with column vectors, you need to transpose your data for it to be viewed as rows: `df.scatter.plot(df.T[0],df.T[1])`

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

geometry = pd.Series([
       [150.792711, -34.210868],
       [151.551228, -33.023339],
       [148.92149870748742, -34.767207772932835],
       [151.033742, -33.919998],
       [150.953963043732, -32.3935017885229]])

df = pd.DataFrame(geometry.to_list(), columns = ['x','y'])

plt.scatter(x = df['x'], y = df['y'],
            edgecolor ='black')
plt.grid(alpha=.15)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
import pandas as pd
geometry_coordinates=[[150.792711, -34.210868],
[151.551228, -33.023339],
[148.92149870748742, -34.767207772932835],
[151.033742, -33.919998],
[150.953963043732, -32.3935017885229],
[114.8927165, -28.902492300000002],
[115.34601918477634, -30.041742290803096],
[115.4632611, -30.8581035],
[121.42151909999998, -30.7804027],
[115.69424934340425, -30.680970908597665]]

geometry_coordinates=pd.DataFrame(geometry_coordinates,columns=['lat','long'])
geometry_coordinates.plot.scatter(x='lat',y='long')
```

[image]